Twilio transcription creating request (API, JS)
I was implementing some Twilio functionality, I found out how to start recording the call, and receiving it recordingSid in the end of the call, next goal was to create transcription from that recording, but I need to do it manually, (not by service where you can on automatic transcription from recording), so I tried to make a transcript from recording with all possible ways described in documentation. First was by using twiml SDK and requesting twimlClient.recordings(recordingSid).transcriptions.create - but as support answered to me, create is no longer exist, so another way was by calling API POST https://intelligence.twilio.com/v2/Transcripts but from the documentation there is no detailed described example how to pass recordingSid, or at least mediaUrl, the only thing what was described in example was serviceSid, and channel:{} - but channel is empty, and when I tried a lot of times requesting this endpoint with different params it returned me only errors, and links to no existing pages in documentation.
So the main thing what I need is to make a request to create transcription by recordingSid, and after it finishes if it's possible to get the result without extra requests.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
